# ¿Cómo ejecutar un evento o método desde evento con Vb.Net?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, eventos, ingenieria-del-software, forms-events

Muy buenas tardes, agradezco me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente...
Quiero que se active se activen los eventos Enter y Leave de mis textbox ya que e diseñado un efecto de PlaceHoder para que cuando mi formulario cargue en blanco o sin información me lo muestre de esta manera:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando entro a cada combobox o textbox el forecolor cambia a un color mas oscuro y se habilita un label con el nombre por defecto del control seleccionado y si salgo del control sin realizar ningun cambio se deshabilita mi label y me coloca el texto nuevamente como placeholder con un gris bajito.

El inconveniente esta cuando el formulario se carga con información, me sigue dejando el texto con el color bajito por defecto y no me habilita los labels.

A continuacion dejo los los eventos que utilizo para los controles:

```
 Private Sub TxtLugarExpedicion_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtLugarExpedicion.Enter
    Dim FnPlaceHolder As New Funcionalidad
    FnPlaceHolder.PlaceHolderEnter(LblLugarExp, TxtLugarExpedicion, "Lugar de expedicion")
End Sub

Private Sub TxtLugarExpedicion_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtLugarExpedicion.Leave
    Dim FnPlaceHolder As New Funcionalidad
    FnPlaceHolder.PlaceHolderLeave(LblLugarExp, TxtLugarExpedicion, "Lugar de expedicion")
End Sub
```

Como verán en los dos códigos anteriores están los eventos ENTER y LEAVE. Ahora quiero llamar esos eventos desde otro código para evitar los inconvenientes antes mencionados, quiero recorrer todos los eventos de esos textbox o combobox y ejecutarlos incluyéndolo desde el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub CargarEmpleados()

    Try

        Dim Neg As New Negocio.NEmpleados
        Dim Tabla As New DataTable
        Dim Codigo As String
        Codigo = TxtCodigoEmpleado.Text
        Tabla = Neg.BuscarCodigo(Codigo)

        Dim Controles As Object
        Dim Txt As Guna2TextBox
        Dim Cbx As Guna2ComboBox
        Dim Lbl As Label
        For Each Controles In TabPage1.Controls
            If TypeOf Controles Is Guna2TextBox Then
                Txt = CType(Controles, Guna2TextBox)
                Dim ColorPlaceholder As Color = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
                Txt.Text = Nothing
                Txt.ForeColor = ColorPlaceholder

            ElseIf TypeOf Controles Is Guna2TextBox Then
                Cbx = CType(Controles, Guna2ComboBox)
                Dim ColorPlaceholder As Color = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
                Cbx.ForeColor = ColorPlaceholder

            ElseIf TypeOf Controles Is ComboBox Then
                Cbx = CType(Controles, ComboBox)
                Dim ColorPlaceholder As Color = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
                Cbx.ForeColor = ColorPlaceholder

            ElseIf TypeOf Controles Is Label Then
                Lbl = CType(Controles, Label)

                Lbl.Visible = True


            End If
        Next
        TxtCodigoEmpleado.Text = Codigo
        CbxTipoDocumento.Text = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("TIPO DOCUMENTO")
        TxtNumeroID.Text = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("NUMERO DOCUMENTO")
        TxtLugarExpedicion.Text = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("LUGAR EXPEDICION")
        DtpFechaExpedicion.Value = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("FECHA EXPEDICION")
        TxtPrimerNombre.Text = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("PRIMER NOMBRE")
        TxtSegundoNombre.Text = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("SEGUNDO NOMBRE")
        TxtPrimerApellido.Text = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("PRIMER APELLIDO")
        TxtSegundoApellido.Text = Tabla.Rows(0).Item("SEGUNDO APELLIDO")

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

No se si me estoy complicando o si hay una manera mas fácil les agradezco de corazón quise ser lo mas claro.

Comment: a ver.. empezemos por los multiples tags que no tienen absolutamente nada que ver... esto no es vba, no es sql, no tiene nada que ver con visual studio... agregar todo eso, atrae atencion negativa a tu publicacion.... luego, vos podes llamar cualquier evento desde cualquier lado.. mientras le pases los parametros que corresponde, o null, podes hacer lo que quieras... ahora, tal vez, deberias tener un metodo generico por fuera de los enters y los leave que maneje eso, es mas, usando el sender como uno de los parametros, porque el sender te dice que objeto llamo al metodo..

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi y como hago para recorrer todos los controles que tengan esos eventos y ejecutarlos desde otro codigo? 
`For Each Controles In TabPage1.Controls
   If TypeOf Controles Is Guna2TextBox Then
    Txt = CType(Controles, Guna2TextBox)
    txt_leave(sender,e)
    txt_enter(sender,e)
  End if
Next`
Algo así como eso...

Comment: Tendrias que recorrer el arbol de controles.. aunque yo siempre prefiero ya tener la referencia y llamar a un metodo que lo hago solo, sin tener que recorrer nada.. pero esto ya es a gusto personal...